# Upgrading complex content types from D6 to D7

Tags: nodes, entities, upgrading

I have a Drupal V6 website with some complex content types that I have created using [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [Contemplate](http://drupal.org/project/contemplate). That is, the content types have fields of type Text, Integer, [Link](https://drupal.org/project/link), Node Reference and so on. I've been unable to upgrade this website to Drupal V7.

I have a few Drupal websites without complex content types and I've been able to upgrade those so I think I understand the general upgrade concepts and procedures. However I'm having trouble with this particular site. The process seems to complete normally, but nodes with complex content types have not migrated and only their basic fields can be displayed and edited. Checking the DB, the raw data appears to be there.

I've read the standard upgrade procedure and the [CCK upgrade procedure](https://drupal.org/node/1144136) but with no luck. Has anyone done this themselves and can you outline the steps you took.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same Problem, but when you follow cck upgrade procedure step by step, it works. I think you need additional Variable Check Module. After upgrade i had 2 corrupted vars. With Variable Check you can find corrupted vars and remove them.

My solution:

1. many cck fields are included in core
2. download and unpack missing modules in to sites/all/modules
3. download "[cck 7.x version](https://drupal.org/project/cck)", "[variable check](https://drupal.org/project/variablecheck)" and unpack
4. after upgrading activate "Variable Check" and "CCK Content Migrate" modules
5. run upgrade.php
6. under admin/reports/variablecheck check the validity of settings in the variable table

Comment: I followed these steps again (as outlined in this answer) and the procedure mostly worked this time. I say mostly, because I was able to migrate the fields successfully. However, I'm still stuck with content templates as my nodes don't display properly. This also appears to be causing other errors as I cannot view some nodes as I get a HTTP 500 error.

Comment: I didn't need the `variable check` module. It reported all variables were okay.

Comment: A few additional tips: you must set a maximum length on text fields of <= 255 on your D6 website before you upgrade; after you perform the D6->D7 upgrade, enable all field related modules and then migrate.